# Sencha touch 2~add, delete, update a data record by using jersey

Tags: jersey, sencha-touch-2, addition, updates

I am new for sencha touch. I need to add , update a data record detail. But I don't have any idea. Here is my sample code

View.js

```
    Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.Loyalty', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'loyaltycard',
       requires: [

    'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.TransactionList',
    'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberPopUp',
     'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberDetail',


    'Ext.ux.keypad.Keypad',
    'Ext.Img'



    ],
    config: {
//        iconCls: 'add_black',
//        title :'Loyalty Point',
        styleHtmlContent: true,
        cls: 'styledContent',
//        
         layout: 'hbox',
         border: 3,
         ui: 'round',
         defaults: {
                margin : '10 10 10 10',
                 padding : 10
             },

        items :[


           {
                flex: 1,
                cls :'containerRadious' ,
                xtype :'container',

                items :[
                    {
                         xtype: 'fieldset',
                        title: 'Welcome, new member ~<i><u>Kenny</u></i>',
                          defaults: {
                            labelWidth: '35%',
                            style: 'font-size:1.0em'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {

                                xtype: 'image',
                                src: 'resources/images/user3.png',
                                height: 100,
                                margin:20

                            },



                            {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name : 'Name',
                                label: 'Name',
                                value :'Kenny Chow',
                                readOnly: true
                            },
                             {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name : 'Age',
                                label: 'Age',
                                value :'20',
                                readOnly: true
                            },
                             {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name : 'Point Available',
                                label: 'Point Available',
                                 value :'50',
                                 id :'pointAvalaible',
                                 readOnly: true
                            },
                             {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                name : 'Last Visited',
                                label: 'Last Visited',
                                value :'27/12/2012 11:53 AM',
                                readOnly: true
                            },
                            {
                                xtype:'button',
                                 text: 'Add',
                                 handler: function() {

                                 }

                            },

                            {
                                xtype:'button',
                                 text: 'Delete',
                                 handler: function() {


                                 }


                            },

                            {
                                xtype:'button',
                                 text: 'update',
                                 handler: function() {


                                 }


                            }

                        ]

                    }
                ]

            },


            {
                 flex: 2,
                 xtype :'container',
                  cls :'containerRadious' ,

                 items :[
                     {


                         centered : true,
                         xtype :'keypad',
                         margin : '30',


                     }


                 ]


            }




        ],


   }

});
```

Model.js

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'memberModel',
        fields: [
            { name: 'memberId' },
            { name: 'name' },
            { name: 'messages' },
            { name: 'imgUrl' },
            { name: 'age' },
            { name: 'address' },
            { name: 'pointAvalaible' },
            { name: 'lastVisited' },

        ]
    }
});
```

Store.js

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   requires: [
//        'bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList'
    ],

    config: {
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function (record) {
                return record.get('name')[0];
            }
        },

          proxy: {
                   type: 'ajax',
                   api: {
                     create : 'index.php?r=show/add',
                     read   : 'index.php?r=show/read',
                     update : 'index.php?r=show/update',
                     destroy: 'index.php?r=show/delete'
                   }
                },

           model :'memberModel',
           storeId :'memberStore',
           autoLoad:false,
           pageSize: 5,
           clearOnPageLoad: false, 

        data: [{
            memberId: 'Kenny',
            name: 'Kenny Chow',
            imgUrl: 'resources/images/user3.png',
            age: '20',
            address:'The Business Centre , 61 Wellfield Road , Roath, Cardiff, CF24 3DG',
            pointAvalaible :'10',
            lastVisited: '26/11/2012, 11:52 AM',




        }, {
            memberId: 'Anthony',
            name: 'Anthony Tan',
            imgUrl: 'resources/images/user3.png',
            age: '21',
            address:'3 Edgar Buildings , George Street , Bath , England , BA1 2FJ',
            pointAvalaible :'45',
            lastVisited: '27/11/2012, 09:52 AM'
        },

        {
            memberId: 'Nicholas',
            name: 'Nicholas Chen',
            imgUrl: 'resources/images/user3.png',
            age: '22',
            address: '91 Western Road , Brighton ,East Sussex ,England ,BN1 2NW ',
            pointAvalaible :'30',
            lastVisited: '30/11/2012, 15:52 PM'
        },

        {
            memberId: 'Admin2',
            name: 'Admin2',
            imgUrl: 'resources/images/user3.png',
            age: '30',
            address: '50 Eestern Road , Brighton ,West Sussex ,England ,BN1 34W ',
            pointAvalaible :'120',
            lastVisited: '01/12/2012, 15:52 PM'
        },

         {
             memberId: 'Ahmad',
             name: 'Ahmad Mohamad',
             imgUrl: 'resources/images/user3.png',
             age: '25',
              address:'Office 33 ,27 Colmore Row ,Birmingham, England ,B3 2EW',
                 pointAvalaible :'32',
              lastVisited: '30/11/2012, 18:52 PM'
         }
         ,

          {
             memberId: 'AronTan',
             name: 'Tan Wan Hua',
             imgUrl: 'resources/images/user3.png',
             age: '26',
              address:'Office 33 ,27 Colmore Row ,Birmingham, England ,B3 2EW',
                 pointAvalaible :'32',
              lastVisited: '30/11/2012, 18:52 PM'
         },

          {
             memberId: 'Justin',
             name: 'Wong Choon Wah',
             imgUrl: 'resources/images/user3.png',
             age: '25',
              address:'Office 33 ,27 Colmore Row ,Birmingham, England ,B3 2EW',
                 pointAvalaible :'32',
              lastVisited: '30/11/2012, 18:52 PM'
         },

          {
             memberId: 'User5',
             name: 'User2',
             imgUrl: 'resources/images/user3.png',
             age: '25',
              address:'Office 33 ,27 Colmore Row ,Birmingham, England ,B3 2EW',
                 pointAvalaible :'32',
              lastVisited: '30/11/2012, 18:52 PM'
         }



        ]
    }
});
```

Please provide me some example

Comment: What have you tried already for Server side code using Jersey? Have a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to get started using Jersey for implementing the server side code.
Here's what I would suggest:

1. Start **listing down the services** that you would need. (Add/ Update data record detail)
2. **Have a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/) tutorial** by **mkyong** for getting started with Jersey.
3. **Implement the first cut** which works.
4. **Try to improve and iterate** by reading more about Jersey features (Annotations, POJO Mapping, ExceptionMapper etc.)